# FB javascript SDK not closing blank popup during log in?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

We have implemented facebook login using FB javascript SDK, it works many times but sometimes when we click the login button it popsup the FB login screen and freezes. We are not sure why it is hanging.

P.S We have loaded the FB scripts asynchronously in out directive and the channel URL is also set.

Below is the code:

```
myapp.directive('facebook', function($http, httpServices) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    controller: function($scope, $attrs) {
        // Load the SDK Asynchronously
        (function(d) {
            var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk',
                ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {
                return;
            }
            js = d.createElement('script');
            js.id = id;
            js.async = true;
            js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
            ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
        }(document));

        function login() {
            FB.login(function(response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    console.log(response)
                    $scope.fbLogin(response.authResponse.accessToken)
                    console.log('FB.login connected');
                } else {
                    console.log('FB.login cancelled');
                }
            }, {
                scope: 'email,user_location,user_birthday'
            });
        };


        $scope.fetch = function() {
            if ($scope.login_status != 'connected') {
                login()
            }
        };
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
        // Additional JS functions here
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
                appId: attrs.facebook, // App ID
                channelUrl: '//localhost:8000/static/js/channel.html', // Channel File
                status: true, // check login status
                cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                xfbml: true // parse XFBML
            });
        }; // end of fbAsyncInit
    }
  }});
```

Comment: Any solution found for this?